# Use Powershell to get 4 properties from an AD user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to write a script to output the `Description`, `Enabled`, `CanonicalName`, `Memberof` properties of ADusers into a text file. I have the following line of code but it outputs 13 different properties and my boss wants to be able to just see the 4 listed properties. Here is the code:

```
Get-ADuser -Identity TestUser -Properties Description, Enabled, CanonicalName, Memberof | Out-File C:\Scripts\Output\ADInfo4Jen.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. ou were telling the Cmdlet to add those properties to the output, but not filtering the others

```
Get-ADuser -Identity TestUser -Properties Description, Enabled, CanonicalName, Memberof |
Select-Object -Property Description,Enabled,CanonicalName,Memberof |
Format-List
```

also Export-CSV would give you a much cleaner output that you can look at in Excel

Comment: This worked nicely, TY. When I replaced Format-List with Export-CSV the Memberof field is populated by "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection" . I have a feeling I am going to have to change this for the boss anyways as I think she is looking for a more friendly name like you get with     >Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User | Select-Object Name | Out-File C:\Scripts\Output\termusers\"$user"_Groups.txt

Comment: Why not get their first and last name with the same command and append it to your file?

`Get-ADuser -Identity TestUser -Properties Description, Enabled, CanonicalName, Memberof | Select-O
bject -Property givenName,surname,Description,Enabled,CanonicalName,Memberof`

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I meant that she would like a more friendly name of Groups the user is a member of. The Boss is dealing with auditors and wants this report to output easily understood group names like Everyone;US_Sales;ECT